# How can I insert videos into my Q&A?

Tags: support

Some people give visual appealing answers with a video/gif.

I saw that those link to i.stack.imgur.com. How can I use that service to automatically transform my blender screencasts (avi jpg) into gifs? If I try to use the site directly I need to provide a link instead of a local file for conversion.

Since stackexchange partnered with imgur (as the above link suggests) there should be an easy way to convert local files to gifs right?

I cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: As far as I know, there is none. This would be a pretty expensive service to provide anyway, so I doubt that would happen very easily.

Answer (score 3):

**Stack-Exchange does not provide such a service**, however some sites online do provide this.
One site you could try would be [**ezgif.com/video-to-gif**](http://ezgif.com/video-to-gif). This site will let you temporarily upload a video file and convert it to a GIF, which you cn then download and upload to the standard image hosting service that Stack-Exchange uses as a whole. You can also do this for individual images as well.

However, I would **strongly discourage** making a video or image sequence and then converting it online. You can use a local program like [**LiceCAP**](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to **record directly to an animated GIF file**, which can then be easily uploaded directly. To insert them into your question and/or answer you just upload them like a standard image file. Notice that the **maximum file size is 2mb**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to just use Youtube videos for video files, especially if your instructions are extensive. Gifs should be for very short, easily remembered actions, such as a clicking a few buttons or so.